# findOne() returns entire document, instead of a single object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to query this set of data using `findOne()`:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c1a4ba1482bf501ed20ae4b"
    },
    "wardrobe": {
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "T-shirt",
                "colour": "Gray",
                "material": "Wool",
                "brand": "Filson",
                "_id": "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a"
            },
            {
                "type": "T-shirt",
                "colour": "White",
                "material": "Acrylic",
                "brand": "H&M",
                "_id": "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a"
            }
        ]
    },
    "tokens": [],
    "email": "another@new.email",
    "password": "$2a$10$quEXGjbEMX.3ERdjPabIIuMIKu3zngHDl26tgRcCiIDBItSnC5jda",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-12-19T13:46:09.365Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2018-12-19T13:47:30.123Z"
    },
    "__v": 2
}
```

I want to return a single object from the `items` array using `_Id` as a filter. This is how I'm doing that:

```
exports.deleteItem = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({ 'wardrobe.items': { $elemMatch: { "_id": "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a",} } }, (err, item) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (err) {
        return console.log("error: " + err);
        }
        res.redirect('/wardrobe');      
    });
  };
```

However, `console.log(item)` returns the whole document—like so:

```
{ wardrobe: { items: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  tokens: [],
  _id: 5c1a4ba1482bf501ed20ae4b,
  email: 'another@new.email',
  password:
   '$2a$10$quEXGjbEMX.3ERdjPabIIuMIKu3zngHDl26tgRcCiIDBItSnC5jda',
  createdAt: 2018-12-19T13:46:09.365Z,
  updatedAt: 2018-12-19T13:47:30.123Z,
  __v: 2 }
```

I want to eventually use this to delete single items, so I need to filter to the single object from the subdocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your question:
MongoDB always returns the full object matching your query, unless you add a projection specifying which fields should be returned.
If you really want to only return a nested object, you could use the aggregation pipeline with the $replaceRoot operator like this:

```
User.aggregate([
 // you can directly query for array fields instead of $elemMatching them
 { $match: { 'wardrobe.items._id': "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a"}}},
 // this "lifts" the fields wardrobe up and makes it the new root
 { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$wardrobe'}
 // this "splits" the array into separate objects
 { $unwind: '$items'},
 // this'll remove all unwanted elements
 { $match: { 'items._id': "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a" },
 },
])
```

This should return only the wanted items.

A note though: If you plan to remove elements from arrays anyways, I'd rather suggest you have a look at the $pull operation, which can remove an element from an array if it matches a certain condition:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

```
User.update(
  { 'wardrobe.items._id': "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a"},
  { $pull: { 'wardrobe.items': {_id: "5c1a4b7d482bf501ed20ae4a"}},
  { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: Awesome - the $pull method was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!